# How to add a file to my sbt docker:stage folder?

Tags: scala, sbt

When I run

```
sbt docker:publishLocal # or stage
```

I want to add a file or folder to the output folder that it pushes to code to, ie:

```
/target/docker/
```

How can I do this?